# \sin in section heading + xelatex + unicode-math fails to produce \tableofcontents

Tags: unicode-math

The following MWE example demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\arctg{\mathop{\operator@font ArcTg}\nolimits}
\makeatother

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX}}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else
    \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi\fi

\begin{document}
\ifxetex
    This is Xe\LaTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is Lua\LaTeX
\else
    This is pdf\LaTeX
\fi\fi

 \subsubsection{Function $arctg(x)$}

 Function
 \begin{equation}
 \arctg(x)
 \end{equation}

 \subsubsection{Function $\cos(x)$}

 \begin{equation}
 \cos(x)
 \end{equation}

 \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I tried both Miktex and TL. At first run XeTeX produces `.toc` file with extremely long record:

```
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {0.0.2}Function $\mathop {\Umathcode 97=7\symoperators 97\scan _stop: \Umathcode 98=7\symoperators 98\scan _stop:........
```

(here less than 1 percent is shown). At the second run xetex fails to finish the compilation. I did not chech if LuaLatex also fails. The compilation succeeds if `unicode-math` is not loaded.

Comment: off-topic: is`\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{ArcTg}` not suficient?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? If you want just to get rid of the error then use `\protect\sin` in section headers. Using the `amsmath` package also fixes this error by redefining `\sin` in another way (which is compatible with `unicode-math`). Or do you want to understand what happens inside the definition and why it expands?

Comment: It should be `\subsubsection{Function $\arctg(x)$}` rather than `\subsubsection{Function $arctg(x)$}`, right? What happens if you insert the missing backslash character?

Comment: @Mico: The same error as for `\sin` happens, which is expected because the definition is basically the same.

Comment: Without `amsmath` the commands such as `\sin` are all fragile, so they should be prefixed by `\protect` when in moving arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands such as `\cos` (operator names) are fragile, so they should be prefixed by `\protect`.

With `amsmath` the problem is milder, because `\cos` expands to `\qopname\relax{o}{cos}` and `\qopname is robust.

In your setting, you should do

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}
    {\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}}%
    {\def\arctg{\mathop{\operator@font arctg}\nolimits}}%
}
```

so as to uniformize the definitions.

You can also make the commands robust:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
    \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi\fi

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}
    {\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}}%
    {\def\arctg{\mathop{\operator@font arctg}\nolimits}}%
}
\def\protectoperators#1{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@tfor\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\MakeRobust\next}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\protectoperators{%
  \sin\cos\log\ln\arctg % add the other operators
}


\begin{document}

\show\sin

\ifxetex
    This is Xe\LaTeX
\else\ifluatex
    This is Lua\LaTeX
\else
    This is pdf\LaTeX
\fi\fi

\subsubsection{Function $\arctg(x)$}

Function
\begin{equation}
\arctg(x)
\end{equation}

\subsubsection{Function $\cos(x)$}

\begin{equation}
\cos(x)
\end{equation}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Here is the contents of the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {0.0.1}Function $\arctg (x)$}{1}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {0.0.2}Function $\cos (x)$}{1}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you explain why log-like functions were not made robust by `fixltx2` as it was done with many orther fragile commands?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov No idea. The fragility turns out to only be really harmful only with `unicode-math` and without `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I don't understand why you don't use the `\DelareMathOperator` machinery (provided by the `amsmath` package) to generate the macro `\arctg`. And, I don't think much good is done anymore by specifying the option `Renderer=Basic` under LuaLaTeX. At any rate, the following, somewhat streamlined version of your MWE runs flawlessly under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{ArcTg}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
      \usepackage{unicode-math}
      \setmainfont{Cambria}
      \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else
   \ifluatex
      \usepackage{unicode-math}
      \setmainfont[BoldFont={Cambria Bold}]{Cambria}
      \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
   \else
      \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ifxetex
      This is Xe\LaTeX
\else
   \ifluatex
      This is Lua\LaTeX
   \else
      This is pdf\LaTeX
   \fi
\fi

\tableofcontents
\medskip

\section{Function $\arctg(x)$}
\begin{equation} \arctg(x) \end{equation}

\section{Function $\cos(x)$} 
\begin{equation} \cos(x)   \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, loading `amsmath` removes the error. But I cannot accept this as an answer. I need a code to work from within a language module for `babel` where call for `amsmath` would be bad solution. As to `Renderer=Basic`, `lualatex` just ignores it issuing a warning. I guess that `unicode-math` must be fixed to resolve the problem.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov - I'm not sure what your concern is over the use of the `amsmath` package -- quite likely because I have no idea what your `babel` module is supposed to do. To me, the main issue raised by your posting is that the `unicode-math` package appears to make assumptions about what is valid input; loading the `amsmath` appears to "help" `unicode-math`. These issues would appear to apply whether or not `babel` is loaded, no? In general, I can't think of serious downsides to simply recommending that whenever `unicode-math` is loaded, `amsmath` should be loaded as well. Do you disagree?

Comment: Yes, this issue appears no matter if babel is called or not.